# Shifting multiple columns down by one row in R

Tags: r, variables, transform, xts

I have number of columns in my dataset and I need to shift columns 18:101 down by one row. So far, I found this command in another thread to be helfpul and below I apply it to my data:

```
data.xts$AR2_Forecast <- transform(data.xts$AR2_Forecast, AR2_Forecast = c(NA, AR2_Forecast[-nrow(data.xts$AR2_Forecast)]))
```

However, since I have 83 additional columns, changing the names would be quite time-consuming. Is there anything I could use that would save me the time?

I was thinking of something along the lines of:

```
data.xts[18:101]<-
```

but I am not sure how the transform function should look.
The class of my data is "xts", "zoo".

Thanks for any feedback!

Comment: The same approach also works with the `xts` class. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use dplyr::select() along with dplyr::lag() to do this more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the same approach as for one column, e.g. by doing:

```
df[, 18:101] <- rbind(rep(NA, 101-17), df[seq_len(nrow(df)-1), 18:101] )
```

**Edit:**
For xts, try:

```
df[, 18:101] <- rbind(rep(NA, 101-17), coredata(df[1:(nrow(df)-1), 18:101] ))
```

Comment: This method doesn't work, as far as I understand it is because the class of my data is xts, not data.frame